# Source of oauth_token_secret for Evernote Authentication

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, evernote

I am working with the Evernote Python SDK, and proceeding through the Oauth workflow description here.

http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php

How do I get a oauth_token_secret? I have my consumer secret, but don't see how to get the oauth_token_secret.

To retrieve an access token, I believe I will need to use the "get_access_token" function. One of the required arguments there is the oauth_token_secret.

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/blob/master/lib/evernote/api/client.py

I have the other pieces required (oauth_token, oauth_verifier).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can leave that blank.
https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/18710-access-token-secret-returning-blank/

Comment: Thanks, will give this a shot.

Comment: When I leave that argument as a blank string I get a KeyError: 'oauth_token' message in response. This is what I'm trying to enter...

Comment: `auth_token = client.get_access_token('gjones.166A170DC72.687474703A2F2F6C6XXXX16C686F7374.0DAED5A65D9EDE49231B754CEE6BXXXD','','BXXXE3B3CDA07E91D800FD2679DCXXX8')`